# How to send multiple websocket messages with 1 user in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I installed a websocket sampler (https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/downloads/).

I am trying to figure out how do I send n (>1) messages using 1 websocket connection? I set `Number of Threads` to 1 and `loop` to 1. I have 2 samplers: open connection & single write sampler. If I change `loop` to greater than 1, then it opens new connections. Checking `same user on every iteration` did not solve the problem. I tried `constant throughput timer` as well but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Either put `open connection` sampler under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
2. Or put your   `single write sampler` under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and specify the desired number of iterations there

More information:

- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)
- [Example scripts covering various aspects of WebSockets use cases](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/)